# fuzzy timestamp parsing with Python

Tags: python, date, parsing, timestamp

Is there a Python module to interpret fuzzy timestamps like the date command in unix:

```
> date -d "2 minutes ago"
Tue Aug 11 16:24:05 EST 2009
```

The closest I have found so far is dateutil.parser, which fails for the above example.

thanks

Comment: What is your idea of "fuzzy" in the example? The fact that you are specifying a relative offset? Or the syntax of doing this ("2 minutes ago")? Would "N - 00:02:00" be fuzzy as well? Or is it because you include the notion of "now", which is ever changing?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Check out this open source module: [parsedatetime](https://github.com/bear/parsedatetime)

Answer (score 2):

[dateparser](https://dateparser.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)

Usage:

```
>>> import dateparser
>>> dateparser.parse('2 minutes ago')
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 27, 13, 44, 54, 993170)
>>> dateparser.parse('yesterday at 15:12')
datetime.datetime(2018, 11, 26, 15, 12)
```

Answer (score 1):

I have been dabbling with this using pyparsing - you can find my latest attempt [here](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/UnderDevelopment#toc0).  It works for these test cases:

```
today
tomorrow
yesterday
in a couple of days
a couple of days from now
a couple of days from today
in a day
3 days ago
3 days from now
a day ago
now
10 minutes ago
10 minutes from now
in 10 minutes
in a minute
in a couple of minutes
20 seconds ago
in 30 seconds
20 seconds before noon
20 seconds before noon tomorrow
noon
midnight
noon tomorrow
```