# Python: convert free text to date

Tags: python, time, parsing, freetext

Assuming the text is typed at the same time in the same (Israeli) timezone, The following free text lines are equivalent:

```
Wed Sep  9 16:26:57 IDT 2009
2009-09-09 16:26:57
16:26:57
September 9th, 16:26:57
```

Is there a python module that would convert all these text-dates to an (identical) `datetime.datetime` instance?

I would like to use it in a command-line tool that would get a freetext date and time as an argument, and return the equivalent date and time in different time zones, e.g.:

```
~$wdate 16:00 Israel
Israel:        16:00
San Francisco: 06:00
UTC:           13:00
```

or:

```
~$wdate 18:00 SanFran
San Francisco  18:00:22
Israel:        01:00:22 (Day after)
UTC:           22:00:22
```

Any Ideas?

Thanks,

Udi

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258712/fuzzy-timestamp-parsing-with-python/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) seems to be a very capable module for this specific task.

Answer (score 6):

The [python-dateutil](http://labix.org/python-dateutil) package sounds like it would be helpful. Your examples only use simple HH:MM timestamps with a (magically shortened) city identifier, but it seems able to handle more complicated formats like those earlier in the question, too.

Comment: Seems great, checking it out.

Comment: Yes, dateutil.pareser.parse() is the relevant method in question.

Answer (score 0):

You could you [`time.strptime`](http://docs.python.org/library/time.html#time.strptime)

Like this :

```
time.strptime("2009-09-09 16:26:57", "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S")
```

It will return a struct_time value (more info on the python doc page).

Comment: Yes, but I'm looking for a module that would do the parsing for me - I guess this work has been done before.