# parsing a text string for dates - not the standard convert problem!

Tags: python, parsing

Does anyone know of a library - ideally Python, that can have a stab at pulling dates out of text?

"Shall we go to the library today"  -> 21 Jan 10
"Starting on the 1st of January" -> 1 Jan 10
"Anytime between 3nd and 5th of Feb 2009"  -> 3 Feb 09, 5 Feb 09

It's a tough problem and probably why I havn't found anything! 
Already using NLTK by the way if that helps.

Comment: Not that I know of any, but does it need to be international or US only? US only could be done with a set of regexes but internationalreally increases the amount of regexes :(

Comment: dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258712/fuzzy-timestamp-parsing-with-python and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1822787/parsing-dates-from-free-text-input-in-python among many others

Comment: fuzzy is a good search term.  Following suggested threads above found this, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258712/fuzzy-timestamp-parsing-with-python/1378134#1378134 which looks promising.  And yes, international is required sigh.

Comment: These answers indeed parse strings related to time, but don't help with extracting time phrases from free text.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [PyParsing](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com) site has a little bonus script for [parsing time expressions](http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/UnderDevelopment#toc0). I would say that is worth a look for you!

Edit: I see you already ended up there as I was typing my suggestion.  Good luck to you!

Answer (score 4):

Looks like this module is what you are looking for: [parsedatetime](http://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/)

Comment: You'll probably have to tokenize your lines before moving them to the parser.

Comment: Should have added to question - have been trying with this but it is easily fooled and then you have the problem of working out if the result is valid!  Thanks for suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the contributions - in the end I followed up one of the comments, that led to pyparsing, which led to the beginnings of a solution.  many thanks all.

Have posted the work in progress, two pyparsing snippets of code here http://pbjots.blogspot.com/2010/01/using-pyparsing-to-extract-dates-from.html in case they help anyone.