# How do you do a fuzzy string to date in python

Tags: python, datetime

i'm passing a string to a function of mine which needs to turn the string into a date.  The string is created by "the user" so it could be anything like:

5p - which means 5pm today (or tomorrow if it's after 5pm),
5:00 - which would mean the next 5 (am or pm).
tuesday 5pm - etc

I am aware of the fact that there are certain python modules (partially) acchieving what I am looking for, but I would like to be able to extend these solutions to supply new date formats into my parsing engine.

Is there any library that gets close to this?

Comment: Will you please post the code you've written so far

Comment: The code i've written so far is just a normal chat bot client that stores chats.  I'm adding the ability for it to store reminders.

Comment: the natural language time parser isn't quite what I need, but the fuzzy timestamp one seems like it's promising.  Maybe i'l submit patches to it if I upgrade it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's [parsedatetime](https://code.google.com/p/parsedatetime/) which tries to do it but as you can guess it's not perfect - ideally you would have a format, especially since you control the string being passed.

Duplicate: [fuzzy timestamp parsing with Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1258712/fuzzy-timestamp-parsing-with-python)

Comment: This one is the closest i'll get probably.  I suppose for the ones it doesnt work for i'll just write my own.

Comment: since you're passing it; just using either the standard lib or seconds since the epoch would be much easier :)

Comment: Just a sidenote: For Javascript implementation check out Chrono, https://github.com/wanasit/chrono